# Session have same equal result but must diffrent

Tags: php, session

I am using this code :

```
@session_start();

//extra codes for db connected...
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT id FROM messages WHERE user='1");
$count = @mysql_num_rows($result);
$msj = intval($_SESSION['newmsg']); //if session is empty, will come 0
echo "($count : $msj) ";
if ($count > $msj) { echo "You have a new message"; } else { echo "No new message"; }
$_SESSION['newmsg']=$count;
```

I want get new messages but when I try I get the same equal results.

For example : I added new one record to DB manually and I did refresh page. Result did come like this: 
(1 : 1) No new message

I added two records to db and I did refresh page. 
Result did come like this: 
(3 : 3) No new message

How can come like this :
(3 : 1) You have a new message

Comment: typo on your select query? - `SELECT id FROM messages WHERE user='1` - remove the `'` in front of the `1`

Comment: `mysql_*` - This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: @sebastianbrosch Thanks, I will consider your suggestions for php 7.0.0. I forgot add last quotes ' to here after 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code...

```
@session_start();

//extra codes for db connected...
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT id FROM messages WHERE user='1");
$count = @mysql_num_rows($result);
$msj = intval($_SESSION['newmsg']); //if session is empty, will come 0
echo "($count : $msj) ";
if ($count > $msj) { echo "You have a new message"; $_SESSION['newmsg']=$count; } else { echo "No new message"; }
```

Comment: Noel B. thanks for your answer. Your code worked partially. But there is a strange situation. For example; If have 20 records in DB and I added 1 record to DB, result did come like this : (21 : 21) Why didn't come like this :   (21 : 20) When I added more records than 1 record result did come true. (when db records is 21 I added two records and result did come 23 : 22)

Comment: maybe your query is wrong... `SELECT id FROM messages WHERE user='1'` if user field is in integer datatype then don't use qoute

Comment: Noel B I edited setInterval function with ajax post options and also I did newmsg session empty one time and I did try again. Now worked. Thanks for your helps. I will consider your suggestions about don't use qoute if datatype is integer.